Am I owed another paycheck for the month of March?
I am paid on a semi monthly basis. My original pay dates were the 15th and last day of the month. On March 1 our pay dates changed to the 5th and 20th of the month. I didn’t receive another check after February 29 until March 20th and it was only a check for 86.67 hours, am I owed an additional check for the month of March? Paychecks received thus far:
1/15,1/31,2/15,2/29,3/20, 04/05 all for 86.67 hrs each.

Ask your manager to ask payroll what happened.

You'll need to ask your employer.

It's likely that they're just changing their pay dates to be 5 days in arrears to have more time to process last-minute changes. I echo others that you need to ask your payroll department.

You'll have to confirm with your employer, but I don't think they skipped paying you.
It looks like they shifted payday back, so your end of month paycheck now comes on the 5th of the next month and the mid-month paycheck comes on the 20th. Since you got paid on 2/29 it wouldn't make sense to also get paid on 3/5. March is where the delay kicks in, and barring additional changes will be the only month you get just one paycheck.

Likely they've just added a delay so that instead of paying people on the last day of the pay period they have a few days to validate/process payroll.

I was not paid the the additional days in March, I was still given my flat 86.67 hours for March 20th paycheck. I’m also and paid hourly.

@Mylene Your April 5th paycheck was likely for those March hours. It's shifting the timing, but not how many hours you're getting paid for. Definitely confirm, but that's not an uncommon scenario to have a paycheck come shortly after the period, especially when hourly
